# Create a custom class using CALayer for UITextField

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to create a custom class that will basically create a bottom border on my UITextField. The issue is that I am going to have multiple UITextFields that are underlined, and rather than duplicate code I figured I create a custom class. Here's the code:

```
    CALayer *border = [CALayer layer];
    CGFloat borderWidth = 2;
    border.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    border.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.emailTextField.frame.size.height - borderWidth, self.emailTextField.frame.size.width, self.emailTextField.frame.size.height);
    border.borderWidth = borderWidth;
    [self.emailTextField.layer addSublayer:border];
    self.emailTextField.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

How would I be able to replicate this without having to rewrite code over and over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method will be create a method and passing the text field you want to change:

```
-(void)addBorderLayer:(UITextField*)tf{
    CALayer *border = [CALayer layer];
    CGFloat borderWidth = 2;
    border.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    border.frame = CGRectMake(0, tf.frame.size.height - borderWidth, tf.frame.size.width, tf.frame.size.height);
    border.borderWidth = borderWidth;
    [tf.layer addSublayer:border];
    tf.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
}
```

You can just call it like:

```
[self addBorderLayer:self.emailTextField];
[self addBorderLayer:self.anotherTextField];
```

The other solution will be create custom class which inherit from UITextField or you can add extension to UITextField to amend itself.

Comment: This is written in Swift?

Comment: @JohnSmith sorry, I converted it to Objective-C haven't try it in xCode so it could be some typing mistakes.

Comment: Okay, excellent. I actually ended up fixing it myself, but I just didn't want anyone to come along and try to ding you for it. Thanks a lot, Greg!

Comment: For some reason the method isn't being called on the UITextField. It changes nothing. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: I just tried my code it was a couple typing mistakes. I changed it and I called the method from viewDidLoad, everything works fine.

Comment: Ah, it was the addSublayer! Add all the properties and I missed it not being drawn to the view. Makes sense! Thanks!